# Como pegar os dados do formulario sem usar o submit?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, programação-estruturada

então estou com uma dúvida aqui.
Eu precisava pegar os dados referentes a um formulário  e enviar para o meu Ajax 
automaticamente (de uma forma estruturada), sem precisar apertar nenhum botão de submit ou usar uma função de onClick.

Eu montei meu código assim

```
<form id="ladologin">
    <input id="acesso" name="acesso" value="#acesso">
    <input id="senha" name="senha" value="senha">

    <script>
        var form = document.getElementById("ladologin"); 
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        console.log(form):
        //console.log(formData):
    </script>
</form>
```

meu console retorna um erro ao tentar recuperar os dados do formulario

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :?token=R1H7-9X-GAZ3:11 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: funções do tipo "keyup" ou "keydown" podem te ajudar nisso

Answer (score 0):

Se for so para arrumar seu erro no final do seu console.log tem um : ao inves de ;

Para mandar os dados no vc pode tentar como o Walter falou ai em cima.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que você pensa em implementar algo que quando termina de digitar e pressiona uma tecla, exemplo: "Enter" você deseja que ele envie os dados para o servidor HTTP sem a necessidade de um botão de submit, certo?

Seguindo esta linha eu acredito que você possa fazer algo assim:

```js
//Escuta o evento de pressionar alguma tecla
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  //Caso a tecla seja o enter (codigo 13)
  if(event.keyCode == 13) {
     //Valida se algo foi preenchido
     if(dadosPreenchidos()) {
         //Chama a função que envia o formulário
         enviarFormulario();  
     } else {
         alert('Acesso e senha devem ser preenchidos');
     }

  }
});

function dadosPreenchidos() {
   var acesso = document.getElementById('acesso').value;
   var senha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
   return acesso !== "" && senha !== "";
}

function enviarFormulario() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //Após modificar o estado da requisição vc verifica se o servidor respondeu 200 (sucesso) e faz alguma ação
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      alert('Formulario enviado com sucesso');
    }
  };
  //Monta o request com o conteudo preenchido no seu formulario
  var data = new FormData();
  var acesso = document.getElementById('acesso').value;
  var senha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
  data.append('acesso', 'person');
  data.append('senha', 'password');
  //Coloque o caminho do seu servidor / recurso / rota que recebe os dados por POST
  xhttp.open("POST", "sua-rota-http-post", true);
  //Envia os dados
  xhttp.send(data);
}
```